# How to correctly use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to read a number from a user input (string) like:

```
' Where "." is grouping separator and "," is the decimal character
dim strUserInput as string = "172.500,00"
dim ret as double

' Produces 172.5 ("." is the decimal separator)
ret = val(strUserInput)
'
' Alternative Way
' Still producing 172.5
strUserInput = strUserInput.tostring(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 'nothing changes
ret = val(strUserInput)
```

How can I correctly use CultureInfo to return 172,500.00 (or 172500,00 or just 172500) to a double var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation for val](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The Val function recognizes only the
>   period (.) as a valid decimal
>   separator. When different decimal
>   separators are used, as in
>   international applications, use CDbl
>   or CInt instead to convert a string to
>   a number. To convert the string
>   representation of a number in a
>   particular culture to a numeric value,
>   use the numeric type's Parse(String,
>   IFormatProvider) method. For example,
>   use
>   System.Double.Parse(System.String,System.IFormatProvider)
>   when converting a string to a Double.

Answer (score 3):

```
Double.Parse("175.500,00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("whatever culture the input is"))
```

The German culture "de" uses decimal comma and period as thousand separator, so you can use that if you don't know.